# Click checkbox based on label name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes with labels named Headline A and Headline B. I'm trying to come up with a way to activate the checkbox of Headline B if the checkbox of Headline A is checked - and vice versa.

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>HEADLINE A</label>

<input type="checkbox">
<label>HEADLINE B</label>
```

This is what I started on, but I'm afraid it's not even close.

```
if($("label:contains('HEADLINE A')").closest('input').is(':checked')){
$("label:contains('HEADLINE B')").closest('input').is(':checked')
}
```

Do I use regex to match the word 'headline' and then come up with the appropriate action?

Comment: Can't you add IDs or classes to the checkboxes? `is` doesn't change  the `checked` property of a checkbox.

Comment: In this particular case, the system doesn't generate unique IDs and classes for these elements. That's the big challenge for me. I have to target the data inside of the label tag.

Comment: If the structure us known, you can use relative selectors, such as .next('input') and skip the whole ID business.

Comment: are these the only inputs and labels you have

Comment: I should add that these two checkboxes are included in a list of dozens of other checkboxes and different label names. i just have to select these checkboxes based on the name label name 'headline'.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what you need. Is there an event which start all this ? I mean, do you need to activate them simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the application must set the input of html with marked or not, right? Following this premise, I believe the solution is this:

```
var headlineA = $("label:contains('HEADLINE A')").prev('input');
var headlineB = $("label:contains('HEADLINE B')").prev('input');

headlineA.attr('disabled', true);
headlineB.attr('disabled', true);

if(headlineA.is(':checked')){
    headlineB.attr('disabled', false);
}
if(headlineB.is(':checked')){
    headlineA.attr('disabled', false);
}
```

You [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JeBbE/). Just set one of the inputs as html checked.

Comment: Both checkboxes default to disabled on your example. What I want to do is have the checkbox with label 'Headline B' check when I check the box that has label 'Headline A'. And vice versa. The user could check Headline A first and be expected to see Headline B checked.

Comment: Please, checks my update, see if this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/JeBbE/1/

Comment: That's great, Fred. Works well on my end. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`closest` selects the closest parent of an element not the closest sibling, if you want to modify the `checked` property of an input you should use `prop` method instead of `is`.

```
if ( $("label:contains('HEADLINE A')").prev('input').is(':checked') ) {
    $("label:contains('HEADLINE B')").prev('input').prop('checked', true)
}
```

Or:

```
var state = $("label:contains('HEADLINE A')").prev('input').is(':checked');
$("label:contains('HEADLINE B')").prev('input').prop('checked', state);
```

In case that you want to modify the `checked` property based on change event you can try:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).next().text() === 'HEADLINE A'
}).change(function() {
    $("label:contains('HEADLINE B')").prev('input').prop('checked', this.checked)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvLyJ/

Comment: Your solution gave me what I need. Thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two Checkboxes then you can use something like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if( $this.is(':checked')){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($this).prop('checked' , true);
    }

});​
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Cnepa/1/)**

If check/uncheck

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($this).prop('checked' , this.checked);
});​
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is if you have other checkboxes that do not require interference. As the author said, it needs to infer the values ​​via the label.